# Global Costmap Updating Mysteriously

Tags: navigation, costmap, rospy, occupancy-grid, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone! I'm experiencing some weird behavior while using costmaps in `move_base` which I hope someone can shed some light on.

Thanks in advance to anyone who bothers with reading this wall of text and formulating a reply. Please let me know if I missed some important detail, and I'll be happy to add more information to this! :)

But first...

### What I'm Trying to Achieve

I want to access costmap data directly, i.e. read the values from the map while knowing how to related them to `/map` coordinates. This is not complicated, and I believe I've achieved it with `tf` (I might have to debug it a bit, but that's beside the point). Seeing as I'm using Python, using the [Costmap2D](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2D.html) API is out of the question.

As such, I developed...

### My Approach

Given that the costmap is only published once in `/move_base/global_costmap/costmap`, and then updated via `/move_base/global_costmap/costmap_updates`, I've written a small Python node that continuously listens to these, updates the main map and then serves them on a `GetMap` service.

This would allow me to have access to the latest costmap as an `OccupancyGrid` whenever I needed it, which is fine for my purposes. Furthermore, serving the map over a service only on-demand should be substantially easier on bandwidth than constantly publishing all updates.

While testing this with `rviz`, I stumbled upon...

### The Problem

**In short, it seems that the costmap that `rviz` shows is different than the one I'm getting on the `/move_base/global_costmap/costmap` topic.**

I have changed my code to act as a simple passthrough (receiving the costmap on the `/move_base/global_costmap/costmap` topic and publishing it elsewhere) and **restarting my node leads me to see, in `rviz`, an updated map without any messages being published in `/move_base/global_costmap/costmap`** (which is monitored with a `rostopic echo`.

In other words, if I move the robot's 2D pose estimate around, leading it to "pollute" the global costmap with whatever trash it's picking up on its sensors, and then restart my node, this new data will be on the costmap published by **my node**, which at this point accesses **only** the `/move_base/global_costmap/costmap` topic which, according to the `rostopic echo` I'm starting at the beginning of the session, has only a single message being published since the beginning of the session (sequence number `seq` is zero).

What I'm doing is basically:

```
self._global_costmap = rospy.wait_for_message("/move_base/global_costmap/costmap", OccupancyGrid)
```

to get the first costmap, and then

```
rospy.Subscriber("/move_base/global_costmap/costmap_updates", OccupancyGridUpdate, self.costmap_cb)
```

to integrate the updates. **For testing purposes, `self.costmap_cb` is limited to:**

```
self._costmap_pub.publish(self._global_costmap)
```

i.e. it publishes the "initial" map every time an update is received, without touching it at all.

### My Theory

I'm thinking that `rviz` uses the aforementioned Costmap2D API to get updated maps. This way, when I set up a new display pointing to `/move_base/global_costmap/costmap`, it "knows" it's a costmap, and accesses the API to get the latest version instead of the barebones version published in that topic. Somehow, in ways I couldn't figure out on my own, it "knows" which costmap the topic (with a completely different name) refers to, and is somehow messing with my custom node and topic.

### My Set-up:

- Xubuntu 14.04
- ROS Indigo
- Latest versions of packages from repos

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289710/global-costmap-updating-mysteriously/) by [Gonçalo S. Martins](https://answers.ros.org/users/34829/gon%C3%A7alo-s.-martins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Troski](https://answers.ros.org/users/34702/troski/) on 2018-04-27**:
it should be `/map` not `\map`.

**Comment by [Gonçalo S. Martins](https://answers.ros.org/users/34829/gon%C3%A7alo-s.-martins/) on 2018-04-27**:
Corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure I follow everything in your setup, but here's a couple of things that might help you understand what's goin on.

As you already saw, the data can be published in one of two places. `costmap` and `costmap_updates`

The data will be published in `updates` unless one of the following is true .

- The `always_send_full_costmap` parameter is true [code](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d_ros.cpp#L121)
- The costmap changes size/origin [code](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d_publisher.cpp#L130)
- There is [a new subscriber](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/costmap_2d/src/costmap_2d_publisher.cpp#L86). The publisher uses a variant of the traditional [advertise](http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#41fcdf7fd2a2bfa1c42d14d35f8f5a8e) function to ensure the full grid is published to new subscribers.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gonçalo S. Martins](https://answers.ros.org/users/34829/gon%C3%A7alo-s.-martins/) on 2018-05-03**:
Thank you very much for your reply! I'll mark it as accepted as it answers my questions.

So new subscribers get the full map, which makes sense. But how does this happen with no new messages being delivered to `rostopic echo /move_base/global_costmap/costmap`?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-05-03**:
I'm not sure. Sorry.

**Comment by [Gonçalo S. Martins](https://answers.ros.org/users/34829/gon%C3%A7alo-s.-martins/) on 2018-05-04**:
No problem, thank you very much for your answer! I'll sift through the code and (hopefully) figure it out :)